# Howto masquerade Postfix on SMTP session?

Tags: postfix

for security reason (and for other reasons too) I want to hide "Postfix" from SMTP response

now:

```
[root@mail ~]# telnet 127.0.0.1 25
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to 127.0.0.1.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    220 mail.example.biz ESMTP Postfix
```

I need the answer to be only:

```
220 mail.example.biz ESMTP
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change [`smtpd_banner`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_banner). Note that per protocol, `$myhostname` must be the first argument.

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP random mail server bent over and ready.
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Relevant documentation link: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Yes, that's the link I already provided, and better, directly to the exact directive.

Comment: Doh, yes you did.